Can i use different methods with different intervals independently using boost::asio::io_context?
I am trying to implement a c++ code which is supposed to call three different methods independent from each other with different intervals.
For example let's say method_1 is supposed to be called every T1 seconds and method_2 is supposed to be called every T2 seconds, and finally method3 is supposed to be executed with T3 seconds interval.
Can i implement it like below? Is calling the methods sequentially inside a single thread making them dependent to each other? like assuming the interval of method1 is 100s, and T2 is 1s.
isn't calling method1 block calling the method2 every 1s?
Does the is io_context.run() method makes them to be called independent from each other?
enum MethodTypes { FIRST = 0, SECOND = 1, THIRD = 2 };

struct TestTimerContext {
boost::asio::steady_timer timer;
NssStatsTimerContext(boost::asio::io_context& io) : timer(io) {}
};

Assuming all of the following methods are defined inside a class.
start_process (vector<bool> condistions, vector<uint32> intervals) {
    if (conditions[0]) {
       boost::asio::io_context io_context_first;
       start_method (intervals[0], MethodTypes::FIRST, io_context_1);
    }
    if (conditions[1]) {
       boost::asio::io_context io_context_2;
       start_method (intervals[0], MethodTypes::FIRST, io_context_2);
        
    }
    if (conditions[2]) {
       boost::asio::io_context io_context_3;
       start_method (intervals[0], MethodTypes::FIRST, io_context_3);
    }
}


start_method (uint32 interval, MethodTypes method_type, boost::asio::io_context io_context) {
    io_context.run();
    std::unique_ptr<TestTimerContext> ctx;
    ctx           = std::make_unique<TestTimerContext>(io_context);
    auto& ctx_ref = *ctx;
    
    if (interval ==0) {
        func_cb( err, interval, method_type);
    } else {
        
        ctx_ref.timer.expires_after(std::chrono::milliseconds(interval));
        ctx_ref.timer.async_wait([&](const boost::system::error_code& err) mutable {
            func_cb( err, interval, method_type);
        });
    }
}


func_cb (
    const boost::system::error_code& err,
    uint32_t                         interval,
    MethodTypes                         method_type) {

    if (err) {
        cout<<"cb function has an error"<<endl;
        return;
    }

    switch (method_type) {
    case MethodTypes::FIRST:
        method1();
        break;
    case MethodTypes::SECOND:
        methdo2();
        break;
    case MethodTypes::THIRD:
        method3();
        break;
    default:
        cout<<"method type is not supported"<<end;
        return;
    }

    if (interval == 0) {
        // do nothing
    } else {
        auto  ctx     = Arc<TestTimerContext>(io_context_);
        auto& ctx_ref = *ctx;

        ctx_ref.timer.expires_after(std::chrono::milliseconds(interval));
        ctx_ref.timer.async_wait([&](const boost::system::error_code& err) mutable {
            func_cb(err, interval, method_type);
        });
    }
}

UPDATED:
This is follow up question:
Thanks @sehe for your comprehensive response and thanks @Christian Stieber for your comments.
I have also confirmed that what @sehe has mentioned i working perfectly.
The other question i have is that let's assume trace() method has some dependency and cannot be finalized in 0ms, then it seems like the posted solution will not work properly.
For example if i call trace method like below:
static inline void method_with_delay(std::string const& msg, int delay) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delay));
    static auto const start = now();
    std::cout << std::setw(10) << (now() - start) / 1ms << "ms " << quoted(msg) << std::endl;
}

and assume that we call them like
asio::io_context ioc;
IntervalTimer t1(ioc.get_executor(), 2000ms,    [] { method_with_delay("Method 1", 100); });
IntervalTimer t2(ioc.get_executor(), 1500ms,    [] { method_with_delay("Method 2", 100); });
IntervalTimer t3(ioc.get_executor(), 1200ms,    [] { method_with_delay("Method 3", 300); });

ioc.run_for(6s);

In that case i can see with above approach sometimes it doesn not work perfectly. Also the order of calling them will be important like if the very beginning call has a larger delay the result will get the worst result.
So, following back to what @Christian Stieber has kindly mentioned.
I was trying to call them through separate threads like below:
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using duration            = std::chrono::steady_clock::duration;
static constexpr auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now;
using boost::system::error_code;



template <typename Callback> struct IntervalTimer {
    IntervalTimer(asio::any_io_executor ex, duration interval, Callback callback)
        : interval_(interval)
        , cb_(std::move(callback))
        , tim_(ex, interval_) 
    {
        loop();
    }

    IntervalTimer(){};

  private:
    void loop() {
        while (tim_.expiry() <= now())
            tim_.expires_at(tim_.expiry() + interval_);

        tim_.async_wait([this](error_code ec) {
            if (!ec) { // aborted or other failure
                cb_();
                loop();
            }
        });
    }

    duration           interval_;
    Callback           cb_;
    asio::steady_timer tim_;
};

static inline void trace(std::string const& msg) {
    static auto const start = now();
    std::cout << std::setw(10) << (now() - start) / 1ms << "ms " << quoted(msg) << std::endl;
    
}

static inline void method_with_delay(std::string const& msg, int delay, asio::io_context& ioc) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delay));
    static auto const start = now();
    std::cout << std::setw(10) << (now() - start) / 1ms << "ms " << quoted(msg) << std::endl;
    ioc.run();
}


int main() {
    trace("main");
    asio::io_context ioc;
    //boost::asio::io_context& ioc_ref = ioc;
    
    std::thread first_thread = std::thread([&]() {
        IntervalTimer t1 (ioc.get_executor(), 100ms,     [&] { method_with_delay("Method 1", 100, std::ref(ioc)); });
        std::cout << "thread1 is finished"<<std::endl;
        
    });

    std::thread second_thread = std::thread([&]() {
        
         IntervalTimer t2 (ioc.get_executor(), 1500ms,     [&] { method_with_delay("Method 2", 100, std::ref(ioc)); });
        std::cout << "thread-2 is finished"<<std::endl;
        
    });

    std::thread third_thread = std::thread([&]() {
        
        IntervalTimer t3 (ioc.get_executor(), 1200ms,     [&] { method_with_delay("Method 3", 300, std::ref(ioc)); });
        std::cout << "thread-3 is finished"<<std::endl;
        
    });
    
    if(first_thread.joinable())
        first_thread.join();

    if(second_thread.joinable())
        second_thread.join();
    
    if(third_thread.joinable())
        third_thread.join();

    trace("exit");
}

But it only shows me the messages when the thread is done like
         0ms "main"
thread-2 is finished
thread-3 is finished
thread1 is finished
         0ms "exit"

Any hint why the methods cannot be executed in my example?

Why do you have so many io_contexts? Why do you run them in start_method?

The goal is to run three methods independently from each other. so using separate io_context for each of them

You've never used boost::asio before, right? Generally, you only ever have one io_context; in your case, you'd simply attach 3 timers to it.

@ChristianStieber is it safe to be shared among multiple threads?

@Ashkanxy yes. The way this works is that an io_context piles up work that needs to be done, and processes it one after the other. You may, however, call run on multiple threads, which means the work will be handled in these threads -- whenever a thread is done with a work item, it fetches the next one from the common pool of all the work items currently scheduled on the io_context. io_context is also a class with a much stronger thread-safety guarantee than most other classes.

@ChristianStieber thanks for your comment, i will to run the sample code provided by sehe through separate threads using  the same io_conext to get better feeling and if it goes well i will post it here as well. Can you also please point me to any documentation that shows how thread safety of is io_context  class. I could not find any note about it anywhere online

I accidentally noticed the update/follow-up question. I expected anyone with 3,4k reputation to know, but you should typically post a new question if you have follow-up questions.

Yes.
You would typically use a single io_context (only use seperation in case you need different scheduling e.g. for prioritizing IO over work).
Since your question code is not self-contained, let me opt to write some simpler code for you instead:

For example let's say method_1 is supposed to be called every T1 seconds and method_2 is supposed to be called every T2 seconds, and finally method3 is supposed to be executed with T3 seconds interval.

static inline void trace(std::string const& msg) {
    static auto const start = now();
    std::cout << std::setw(10) << (now() - start) / 1ms << "ms " << quoted(msg) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    trace("main");
    asio::io_context ioc;

    IntervalTimer t1(ioc.get_executor(), 1s,     [] { trace("Method 1"); });
    IntervalTimer t2(ioc.get_executor(), 1500ms, [] { trace("Method 2"); });
    IntervalTimer t3(ioc.get_executor(), 1200ms, [] { trace("Method 3"); });

    ioc.run_for(6s);
    trace("exit");
}

For the purpose, I've invented IntervalTimer to encapsulate a timer object and the async callback loop:
template <typename Callback> struct IntervalTimer {
    IntervalTimer(asio::any_io_executor ex, duration interval, Callback callback)
        : interval_(interval)
        , cb_(std::move(callback))
        , tim_(ex, interval_) 
    {
        loop();
    }

  private:
    void loop() {
        while (tim_.expiry() <= now())
            tim_.expires_at(tim_.expiry() + interval_);

        tim_.async_wait([this](error_code ec) {
            if (!ec) { // aborted or other failure
                cb_();
                loop();
            }
        });
    }

    duration           interval_;
    Callback           cb_;
    asio::steady_timer tim_;
};

See it Live On Coliru
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using duration            = std::chrono::steady_clock::duration;
static constexpr auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now;
using boost::system::error_code;

template <typename Callback> struct IntervalTimer {
    IntervalTimer(asio::any_io_executor ex, duration interval, Callback callback)
        : interval_(interval)
        , cb_(std::move(callback))
        , tim_(ex, interval_) 
    {
        loop();
    }

  private:
    void loop() {
        while (tim_.expiry() <= now())
            tim_.expires_at(tim_.expiry() + interval_);

        tim_.async_wait([this](error_code ec) {
            if (!ec) { // aborted or other failure
                cb_();
                loop();
            }
        });
    }

    duration           interval_;
    Callback           cb_;
    asio::steady_timer tim_;
};

static inline void trace(std::string const& msg) {
    static auto const start = now();
    std::cout << std::setw(10) << (now() - start) / 1ms << "ms " << quoted(msg) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    trace("main");
    asio::io_context ioc;

    IntervalTimer t1(ioc.get_executor(), 1s,     [] { trace("Method 1"); });
    IntervalTimer t2(ioc.get_executor(), 1500ms, [] { trace("Method 2"); });
    IntervalTimer t3(ioc.get_executor(), 1200ms, [] { trace("Method 3"); });

    ioc.run_for(6s);
    trace("exit");
}

Outputting
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
         0ms "main"
      1000ms "Method 1"
      1200ms "Method 3"
      1500ms "Method 2"
      2000ms "Method 1"
      2400ms "Method 3"
      3000ms "Method 1"
      3000ms "Method 2"
      3600ms "Method 3"
      4000ms "Method 1"
      4500ms "Method 2"
      4800ms "Method 3"
      5000ms "Method 1"
      6000ms "Method 1"
      6000ms "exit"

With my local interactive demo:


Thanks @sehe for your response. Is it safe if we call each instantiation of the IntervalTimer in separate threads, assuming they all share the same io_context. Also if we need to stop the timer can it be done by calling io_context.run() and io_context.stop() methods?

Stopping a timer is done with cancel()/cancel_one(). Stopping the service stops "the world", which makes it a scalability issue because now you have to duplicate everything for each timer. In that case, simply making a bespoke monitoring thread is way easier and more effective.

I just noticed the follow up question in your edit. Never block on an IO thread. So, I think it's actually remarkably resilient: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88487dff2e5416be, but obviously you should not be blocking your IO thread if you want to accurately respond to timers... One low-tech workaround would be to ensure enough IO threads: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e2bdaef81de33c1 (timing deviations: https://imgur.com/a/dCf8X8n).

Of course that may break down when you have dynamic number of timers that all have callbacks that may block for unpredictable amounts of time. I bet you can find an optimal tuning for your specific application domain

Thanks for your notes.
Looking at this link
coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e2bdaef81de33c1
i think ioc.join() does not help.
I need to call ioc.stop() instead, otherwise i can see that method-1 and method-2 are executed for a long time.

You can see the actual live output, right? I can only imagine you forgot the .cancel() on the timers?
