How to call different methods with their own sample intervals inside a class using different a TimerInterval class working with io_context
I am trying to use the same idea suggested as answer of my question in this post. Thi goal is to implement a class that will call 3 different methods with their own intervals inside a start_trigger method.
The following sample code is compiled successfully, but it does not work logically since the life time of IntervalTimer objects are limited to the start_process() method rather than class lifetime.
So my solution to resolve this issue is to define 3 variables of IntervalTimer as a class member and then initialize them inside the start_processing method.
The start_process method is a public method and can be called through an object of MyTestClass.
Here is the code that will be compiled with no issue, but it does not repeatedly call three methods (method1, method2, and method3 with the provided intervals).
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using duration            = std::chrono::steady_clock::duration;
static constexpr auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now;
using boost::system::error_code;
using namespace std;




enum MethodTypes { FIRST = 0, SECOND = 1, THIRD = 2 };

using Callback = std::function<void()>;
//template<typename Callback>
struct IntervalTimer {
    IntervalTimer(asio::any_io_executor ex, duration interval, Callback callback)
        : interval_(interval)
        , cb_(std::move(callback))
        , tim_(ex, interval_) 
    {
        loop();
    }

  private:
    void loop() {
        while (tim_.expiry() <= now())
            tim_.expires_at(tim_.expiry() + interval_);

        tim_.async_wait([this](boost::system::error_code const& ec) {
            if (!ec) { // aborted or other failure
                cb_();
                loop();
            }
        });
    }

    duration           interval_;
    Callback           cb_;
    asio::steady_timer tim_;
};

class MyTestClass final {

public:
    MyTestClass(int transaction_id , boost::asio::io_context& io) :
        transaction_id_(transaction_id) ,io_context_(io) {
            //tt1(clone( IntervalTimer()));
        }

    void start_process (vector<int>ids, vector<bool> conditions, map <int, unordered_set<string> >& set_of_items);
    void stop_process();

private:
    void method1 (int id, const unordered_set<string>& set_of_buyers);
    void method2 (int id, const unordered_set<string>& set_of_sellers);
    void method3 (int id, const unordered_set<string>& set_of_units);
    void stats_cb(uint32_t tp_id, MethodTypes method_type, unordered_set<string>& set_of_values);
    int transaction_id_;
    boost::asio::io_context& io_context_;

    //IntervalTimer tt1;
    //IntervalTimer tt2;
    //IntervalTimer tt3;

};

void MyTestClass::start_process(vector<int>ids, vector<bool> conditions, map <int, unordered_set<string> >& set_of_items){
    
    if (conditions[0]) {
        auto     sample_interval = 10;
         //IntervalTimer tt1_tmp (io_context_.get_executor(), std::chrono::milliseconds(sample_interval), [&] {
         // stats_cb(ids[0], MethodTypes::FIRST, set_of_items[0]);
         //});
         //tt1 =std::move(tt1_tmp);
        IntervalTimer t1(io_context_.get_executor(), std::chrono::milliseconds(sample_interval), [&] {
        stats_cb(ids[0], MethodTypes::FIRST, set_of_items[0]);
        });
    }
        if (conditions[1]) {
        auto sample_interval = 20;
        IntervalTimer t2(io_context_.get_executor(), std::chrono::milliseconds(sample_interval), [&] {
            stats_cb(ids[1], MethodTypes::SECOND, set_of_items[1]);
        });
    } 
    if (conditions[1]) {
        auto  sample_interval = 30;
        IntervalTimer t3(io_context_.get_executor(), std::chrono::milliseconds(sample_interval), [&] {
             stats_cb(ids[2], MethodTypes::THIRD, set_of_items[3]);
        });
    } 
    io_context_.run();
}


void MyTestClass::stats_cb(uint32_t id, MethodTypes method_type, unordered_set<string>& set_of_values){

    switch (method_type) {
    case MethodTypes::FIRST:
         method1(id, set_of_values);
         break;
    case MethodTypes::SECOND:
        method2(id, set_of_values);
         break;
    case MethodTypes::THIRD:
        method3(id, set_of_values);
        break;
    default:
         cout<<"the provided  type is not supported"<< endl;
         return;
    }
}


void MyTestClass::method1 (int v, const unordered_set<string>& set_of_values){
     cout<<"method-1 is called and v ="<<v<<endl;
     for (auto e: set_of_values)
        cout<<e<< endl;
     cout<<"method-1 is done"<<endl;
}

void MyTestClass::method2 (int v, const unordered_set<string>& set_of_values){
    cout<<"method-2 is called and v ="<<v<<endl;
    for (auto e: set_of_values)
       cout<<e<< endl;
    cout<<"method-2 is done"<<endl;
}

void MyTestClass::method3 (int v, const unordered_set<string>& set_of_values){
    cout<<"method-3 is called and v ="<<v<<endl;
    for (auto e: set_of_values)
         cout<<e<< endl;
     cout<<"method-3 is done"<<endl;
}



int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context iocx;
    MyTestClass obj(100, iocx);
    vector<int> ids {100,200,300};
    vector<bool> conds {false,true,true};
    map <int, unordered_set<string> > mp;
    mp[0].insert("test1_0");
    mp[0].insert("test1_1");
    mp[0].insert("test1_2");       mp[1].insert("test2_0");
    mp[1].insert("test2_1");
    mp[1].insert("test2_2");       mp[2].insert("test3_0");
    mp[2].insert("test3_1");
    
    obj.start_process(ids, conds, mp);
    return 0;
}

However, when i uncomment the commented parts like the following definition inside the MyTestClass
//IntervalTimer tt1;

and the following one inside the start_process()
 //IntervalTimer tt1_tmp (io_context_.get_executor(), std::chrono::milliseconds(sample_interval), [&] {
 // stats_cb(ids[0], MethodTypes::FIRST, set_of_items[0]);
 //});
 //tt1 =std::move(tt1_tmp);

I get the following compilation errors:
prog.cc: In constructor 'MyTestClass::MyTestClass(int, boost::asio::io_context&)':
prog.cc:53:56: error: no matching function for call to 'IntervalTimer::IntervalTimer()'
   53 |         transaction_id_(transaction_id) ,io_context_(io) {
      |                                                        ^
prog.cc:23:5: note: candidate: 'IntervalTimer::IntervalTimer(boost::asio::any_io_executor, duration, Callback)'
   23 |     IntervalTimer(asio::any_io_executor ex, duration interval, Callback callback)
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:23:5: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided
prog.cc:22:8: note: candidate: 'IntervalTimer::IntervalTimer(IntervalTimer&&)'
   22 | struct IntervalTimer {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:22:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided

Is there any suggestion how to resolve this error?

You can do anything to dynamically construct the IntervalTimer objects. E.g. have a member like
std::list<IntervalTimer> timers;

Then, fixing some copy paste errors as well (conditions[1] is repeated and set_of_items[3] is always the empty set...):
void MyTestClass::start_process(std::vector<int> ids, std::vector<bool> conditions,
                                std::map<int, Set>& set_of_items) {
    auto ex = io_context_.get_executor();
    if (conditions[0])
        timers.emplace_back(ex, 10ms, [&] { stats_cb(ids[0], MethodTypes::FIRST, set_of_items[0]); });
    if (conditions[1])
        timers.emplace_back(ex, 20ms, [&] { stats_cb(ids[1], MethodTypes::SECOND, set_of_items[1]); });
    if (conditions[2])
        timers.emplace_back(ex, 30ms, [&] { stats_cb(ids[2], MethodTypes::THIRD, set_of_items[2]); });
}

There's a big problem that you capture the local ids by reference. This leads to Undefined Behavior. See below.
In general, simplify your code by reducing duplication. There was a LOT of copy/paste mistakes. Also, never using namespace std.
Always use good names for types as well as objects.
When you keep having the same code switching on an index (0,1,2), consider grouping the behavior and data in a class. Don't add useless repetition/indirection like stats_cb, instead just write:
void MyTestClass::start_process(std::vector<int> ids, std::vector<bool> conditions,
                                std::map<int, Items>& set_of_items) {
    if (conditions[0])
        timers.emplace_back(ex_, 10ms, [this, id = ids[0], &items = set_of_items[0]] { method1(id, items); });
    if (conditions[1])
        timers.emplace_back(ex_, 20ms, [this, id = ids[1], &items = set_of_items[0]] { method2(id, items); });
    if (conditions[2])
        timers.emplace_back(ex_, 30ms, [this, id = ids[2], &items = set_of_items[0]] { method3(id, items); });
}

Do not call run inside start_process. MyTestClass doesn't own the io_context (and the name start_process would be wrong, because it also completes the process).
Throwing in stop_process:
void MyTestClass::stop_process() {
    for (auto& t : timers)
        t.cancel();
}

We get
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using duration            = std::chrono::steady_clock::duration;
static constexpr auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now;
using boost::system::error_code;

static auto const start = now();
static inline void trace(auto const&... msg) {
    ((std::cout << (now() - start) / 1ms << "\tms\t") << ... << msg) << std::endl;
}

struct IntervalTimer {
    using Callback = std::function<void()>;
    IntervalTimer(asio::any_io_executor ex, duration interval, Callback callback)
        : interval_(interval)
        , cb_(std::move(callback))
        , tim_(ex, interval_) {
        loop();
    }

    void cancel() {
        post(tim_.get_executor(), [this] { tim_.cancel(); });
    }

  private:
    void loop() {
        while (tim_.expiry() <= now())
            tim_.expires_at(tim_.expiry() + interval_);

        tim_.async_wait([this](error_code const& ec) {
            if (!ec) { // aborted or other failure
                cb_();
                loop();
            }
        });
    }

    duration           interval_;
    Callback           cb_;
    asio::steady_timer tim_;
};

using Items = std::unordered_set<std::string>;
class MyTestClass final {
  public:
    MyTestClass(int transaction_id, asio::any_io_executor ex) : transaction_id_(transaction_id), ex_(ex) {}

    void start_process(std::vector<int> ids, std::vector<bool> conditions,
                       std::map<int, std::unordered_set<std::string>>& set_of_items);
    void stop_process();

  private:
    void method1(int id, Items const& set_of_buyers);
    void method2(int id, Items const& set_of_sellers);
    void method3(int id, Items const& set_of_units);
    int  transaction_id_; // UNUSED

    asio::any_io_executor    ex_;
    std::list<IntervalTimer> timers;
};

void MyTestClass::start_process(std::vector<int> ids, std::vector<bool> conditions,
                                std::map<int, Items>& set_of_items) {
    // for (int id = 0; id < 3; ++id)
    // timers.emplace_back(ex_, 10ms, [id, &items = set_of_items[id]] { method1(id, items); });
    if (conditions[0])
        timers.emplace_back(ex_, 1000ms, [this, id = ids[0], &items = set_of_items[0]] { method1(id, items); });
    if (conditions[1])
        timers.emplace_back(ex_, 2000ms, [this, id = ids[1], &items = set_of_items[0]] { method2(id, items); });
    if (conditions[2])
        timers.emplace_back(ex_, 3000ms, [this, id = ids[2], &items = set_of_items[0]] { method3(id, items); });
}

void MyTestClass::stop_process() {
    for (auto& t : timers)
        t.cancel();
}

void MyTestClass::method1(int v, Items const& set_of_values) {
    trace("method-1", " is called and v =" , v );
    std::cout << "\t\tmethod-1" << " iterating:";
    for (auto const& e : set_of_values)
        std::cout << " " << e;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    trace("method-1", " is done");
}

void MyTestClass::method2(int v, Items const& set_of_values) {
    trace("method-2", " is called and v =" , v );
    std::cout << "\t\tmethod-2" << " iterating:";
    for (auto const& e : set_of_values)
        std::cout << " " << e;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    trace("method-2", " is done");
}

void MyTestClass::method3(int v, std::unordered_set<std::string> const& set_of_values) {
    trace("method-3", " is called and v =" , v );
    std::cout << "\t\tmethod-3" << " iterating:";
    for (auto const& e : set_of_values)
        std::cout << " " << e;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    trace("method-3", " is done");
}

int main() {
    asio::io_context     ioc;
    MyTestClass          obj(100, ioc.get_executor());
    std::map<int, Items> mp = {{0, {"test1_0", "test1_1", "test1_2"}},
                               {1, {"test2_0", "test2_1", "test2_2"}},
                               {2, {"test3_0", "test3_1"}}};

    obj.start_process({100, 200, 300}, {false, true, true}, mp);

    ioc.run_for(8s);
    obj.stop_process();
    ioc.run(); // graceful shutdown
}

Printing
2000    ms  method-2 is called and v =200
        method-2 iterating: test1_2 test1_1 test1_0
2007    ms  method-2 is done
3000    ms  method-3 is called and v =300
        method-3 iterating: test1_2 test1_1 test1_0
3000    ms  method-3 is done
4000    ms  method-2 is called and v =200
        method-2 iterating: test1_2 test1_1 test1_0
4000    ms  method-2 is done
6000    ms  method-2 is called and v =200
        method-2 iterating: test1_2 test1_1 test1_0
6000    ms  method-2 is done
6000    ms  method-3 is called and v =300
        method-3 iterating: test1_2 test1_1 test1_0
6000    ms  method-3 is done
8000    ms  method-2 is called and v =200
        method-2 iterating: test1_2 test1_1 test1_0
8000    ms  method-2 is done

Note that I made the delays much longer just so you can see the output. You can adjust them back to 10ms, 20ms, 30ms.

BONUS
Always group objects and data. The repeated switching on indexes 0,1,2 indicates that something wants to be an entity:
struct Task {
    using Func = std::function<void(int, Items const&)>;

    bool     condition = false;
    duration interval;
    Func     method;
};

If you squint a little you will see that MyTestClass really only adds complications at this point. It looks like a class that takes on too many responsibilities, ironically preventing the entities that need to exist from existing. How about this version:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using duration            = std::chrono::steady_clock::duration;
static constexpr auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now;
using boost::system::error_code;

static auto const  start = now();
static inline void trace(auto const&... msg) {
    ((std::cout << (now() - start) / 1ms << "\tms\t") << ... << msg) << std::endl;
}

struct RecurringTask {
    using Callback = std::function<void()>;
    RecurringTask(asio::any_io_executor ex, duration interval, Callback callback)
        : interval_(interval)
        , cb_(std::move(callback))
        , tim_(ex, interval_) {
        loop();
    }

    void cancel() {
        post(tim_.get_executor(), [this] { tim_.cancel(); });
    }

  private:
    void loop() {
        while (tim_.expiry() <= now())
            tim_.expires_at(tim_.expiry() + interval_);

        tim_.async_wait([this](error_code const& ec) {
            if (!ec) { // aborted or other failure
                cb_();
                loop();
            }
        });
    }

    duration           interval_;
    Callback           cb_;
    asio::steady_timer tim_;
};

using Items = std::unordered_set<std::string>;

void method(std::string_view name, int v, Items const& set_of_values) {
    trace(name, " is called and v = ", v);
    std::cout << "\t\t" << name << " iterating:";
    for (auto const& e : set_of_values)
        std::cout << " " << e;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    trace(name, " is done");
}

int main() {
    asio::io_context ioc;

    int transaction_id_ = 100; // UNUSED

    Items buyers  = {"test1_0", "test1_1", "test1_2"};
    Items sellers = {"test2_0", "test2_1", "test2_2"};
    Items units   = {"test3_0", "test3_1"};

    std::list<RecurringTask> tasks;
 // tasks.emplace_back(ioc.get_executor(), 1000ms, bind(method, "buyers",  100, std::ref(buyers)));
    tasks.emplace_back(ioc.get_executor(), 2000ms, bind(method, "sellers", 200, std::ref(sellers)));
    tasks.emplace_back(ioc.get_executor(), 3000ms, bind(method, "units", 300, std::ref(units)));

    ioc.run_for(8s);
}

Printing
2000    ms  sellers is called and v = 200
        sellers iterating: test2_2 test2_1 test2_0
2016    ms  sellers is done
3000    ms  units is called and v = 300
        units iterating: test3_1 test3_0
3000    ms  units is done
4000    ms  sellers is called and v = 200
        sellers iterating: test2_2 test2_1 test2_0
4000    ms  sellers is done
6000    ms  sellers is called and v = 200
        sellers iterating: test2_2 test2_1 test2_0
6000    ms  sellers is done
6000    ms  units is called and v = 300
        units iterating: test3_1 test3_0
6000    ms  units is done
8000    ms  sellers is called and v = 200
        sellers iterating: test2_2 test2_1 test2_0
8006    ms  sellers is done


Thanks @Sehe, it an amazing response like always. As you shown it works perfectly while the methods are executed with no delay. Assuming each method calls is executed with their own delay, is the best approach to make them independent is running them through separate threads? I can ask it in a separate question, but it will be probably same as earlier question (under updated section) of the other post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78290308/can-i-use-different-methods-with-different-intervals-independently-using-boost

Following back my previous comment let's say if you add the following line in the body of the method() right after calling the the trace method for the first time that prints "is called and v = "
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(v));
Then based on your outputs we can observe that the method call intervals are dependent to each other because they cannot be executed in 0ms.

I see, your second response to my other question. I think your suggestion is to use  asio::thread_pool ioc(4); and later on calling the cancel method and ioc.join().
In that case i think i can define  std::list tasks; as a class member and call tasks.emplace_back(... part in start_process method and probably call the 3 task.cancel(....  and ioc.join() in the stop_process method.
start_ process is when i want to start calling these methods with their own intervals and stop_process is when i want to pause this process.

That's indeed exactly the same question as last time, and the simplest solution is still the same: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5157ac03c17c83f  Since now your solution is multi-threaded, beware of synchronization requirements (e.g. make transaction_id_ const or atomic_int).

Thanks @sehe, is there anyway to confirm that the methods are executed in different threads? I have tried to to print it using boost::this_thread::get_id() in the method() function in this link coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5157ac03c17c83f, but it gets error.
the reason i am asking is that when i try to use the same idea in my project i see different methods are not called in different threads.

Isn't it better to create a vector of pointers to thread_poll like  the one i will post in my next comment and then pass the methods to it through the post command?
I just do not understand how to add the objects of RecurringTask defined in https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5157ac03c17c83f , through post method call

Basically none of these approaches are working
https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65ee4175f22e0b41
Just trying to make sure the methods are executed through a post and in different threads.
also i commented out the line to print the current thread since it gives compilation error

Sure. Just print out a thread id: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3f7ea7cd14c8816 Re.: "Isn't it better" - you tell me?! I don't see why. Your question is very clear to ask about independent timers on steady intervals. If you really want all tasks on a single thread they wait for each other they're definitely not independent.

After reading https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65ee4175f22e0b41... Well. I don't know what to say. You managed to force things back to magic index shuffling and dynamically-allocated-everything. Also, you create multiple threadpools with a system-dependent number of threads (oops?). If for some reason you insist on no shared threads (even though the independent execution is already guaranteed), remember what my answer said (paraphrasing): "Task wants to be an entity". Combine with "MyTestClass doesn't own the io_context" instead: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/30aec47d1843e4a8

You have to pick the right (concrete, cost-effective) guiding points. "Isn't it better" is just a rhetorical. However, your choice to put everything behind [0,1,2] indexes has proven to have a real cost in complexity. I think that's the more important thing to notice. Note how my  "private thread pools" is actually simpler. Of course, your "method1"/"method2"/"method3" really want to be "BuyerPoll", "SellerPoll", "UnitPoll" - but since I cannot see how your program uses the data further I can only make guesses that you will then (rightly) subvert again because it doesn't match your program

Thanks for your notes, yeah it kind of depends on implementing the idea.
So for my case i need to call it inside a class. The class will provide a start and stop public methods that can be called whenever the object of the class is instantiated.
So this is closes sample code to how i am trying to implement it
https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b776a1f97e59d7e9
For my case it errors out with the "error is  Operation is canceled" error. Which is basically the error i added under else part of async_wait().  I can also see a similar error message when i try it here https://wandbox.org/

Yeah. You std::ref to local variables. If you somehow feel it's better to have everything contained in some class that is "NotMain", why don't you do just that: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/374f802c136e59ef (demo run https://imgur.com/a/miOt0au). No need to re-invent lambdas badly with that start_cb red-tape. I see a pattern where you ignore the answer and end up with exactly the problem you started with :/

That makes sense, thanks for your feedback.
I made a minor fix which is supporting interval 0ms. In this case i want to call the method only once, otherwise it loops for ever.
for example let's assume the method which is working on buyers has a large delay and its interval is defined as 0ms. In this case the other two methods which will be called for Sellers and Units are called after the large delay. like this one https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e7946347d3ca0d0. It will be show the result better if you run in wandbox.org. It shows that the execution is delayed for 4s.

for the above example we simulated the execution time with sleep_for(10s), but in my case this decision is made by an external call. So as soon it calls stop() all method calls will be halted, and because of the extra delayed caused by method that is working with buyers (with interval =0  and delay = 4000ms), calling two other methods will be delayed for 4s and basically the other methods are called for a shorter period of time like from 4s - 10s.

Maybe adding the  context_.join(); to the end of cancel method will help? But even if it works, i think  this is not an appropriate solution since we basically extend the execution time after receiving the external stop command.

Again, keep it simple! https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6751c26b2d948bba - there is no reason to suddenly start running stuff on the constructing thread, right? Also, no need to have no timer. You just want to have wait indefinitely https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35774f5f307f2b21. Regarding immediately termination (cancellation is cooperative) that was never the question. It's high time for a new question there.

Oh i see you added  >>>> interval_(interval > 0s ? interval : duration::max()) <<<<
that is one way to address it, basically means for interval == 0 ignores to call a method or define its interval as the largest number, but for my case i need to call the method once in this case.
So wait indefinitely at least does not help for my case.

One approach is to call the method through a separate thread instead of adding the new object of RecurringTask to the list of tasks_. Like checking inside the start if the interval is zero just call the method like
https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a15e152d56f36b7
I get the expected result when i compile it here wandbox.org

Yeah I was a second too fast. I wrote that in hurry before leaving for work. The idea was what matters: you want the cb_ still to happen on the thread - that you took extra steps to make sure was private for the task. This is the better execution of the same idea: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e6d6499b751c4c4

Thanks @Sehe again for your notes. Is there any trick to make sure all of the methods for the first time are called at t=0? Like right now they are called after the sample interval time. for example we have "t=2000 ms sellers start delay = 0.2 n=3".
If i call the cb out side of "tim_.async_wait" then it delayed every other calls based on delay of the method.

My solution is to calls them once with 0ms and once with the real sampleinterval like  https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c229664d8496e2de.
it works fine when i try it in https://wandbox.org/
